# How to center list items of listview?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to center list items of listview? I want header to take the whole width of page list items to take only a certain amount, for example 800 pixels or 60 percent of the screen, etc. It seems that the list wants that list items width would be the same as list's and it's header. I tried to horizontally center items but it does not work and I do not want to use margins because it kills the performance. Any suggestions?

```
<Grid>

        <ListView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ListView.Header>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                             BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                             HeightRequest="300">

                    <Label Text="Header"
                           FontSize="72"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           TextColor="Black"/>

                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Header>

            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                     WidthRequest="800"
                                     BackgroundColor="Green">

                            <Label Text="{Binding . }"
                                   HeightRequest="20"
                                   BackgroundColor="DimGray"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   TextColor="Black"/>

                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the width request , and change the HorizontalOptions to "FillAndExpand"

Comment: You have the right idea already in what you did for group header: have a layout that fills the width, then put a centered item in it. All you need to do differently for items, is move BackgroundColor from StackLayout to Label. Liyun Zhang's answer shows this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the listview's item really center. But you can make it looks like center.

You can try to make the stacklayout fill the view cell and set the label's background and width to make it looks like center. Such as:

```
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                        <Label Text="{Binding . }"
                               WidthRequest="400"
                               HeightRequest="20"
                               BackgroundColor="Pink"                      
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               TextColor="Black"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And the result picture:
[image]